# Trying to set a hub server for togetherjs application and i am using node.js to run the server i get the following error

Tags: javascript

> Error: Cannot find module 'websocket-server'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>       at require (module.js:384:17)
>       at Object. (D:\Rahul\hubServer\togetherjs-develop\togetherjs-develop\hub\websocket-compat.js:27:28)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:365:17)

Comment: To get support you should post your code and it would be best to create a running demo on plunker or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you have not installed that module. To do this do

`npm  install websocket-server`

Usually instead of doing this manually you will have a `package.json` file and you can install all the modules by doing `npm install`

I'd you want to save websocket-server to the package  run this command:

```
npm  install websocket-server --save
```

Remember to do `npm install __` in the directory of where your site is. Otherwise node won't find it.

Comment: i already have websocket-server installed in the same path but it still returning the  same error

Comment: @RahulAhire this could be because you are not adding it to the `package.json ` also jf that doesn't work try doing this: `npm install -g websocket-server ' If that still doesnt work than you will have to provide the code where you require the module.

Comment: can you suggest some links with description on adding websocket  to package.json. Sorry for inconvenience I am totally new to this and this is my first run at installing a hub server through javascript

Comment: @Rahul yep will post in my answer

Comment: If I try:
npm install websocket-server

I get:
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-1020-aws
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "websocket-server"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm v3.5.2

npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues